# Insert graphical representation in linear regression plot in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

Hey there I'm new to R and have a small question

I have the following dataset consisting of 12 different bonds:

```
dput(Synthetic_bond_creation)
structure(list(`Days to maturity` = c(1419, 202, 1565, 1182, 
2080, 1036, 811, 2436, 1296, 609, 1792, 986), `Yield to maturity` = c(2.699, 

0.487, 4.019, 1.421, 2.394, 1.366, 1.107, 2.717, 1.592, 0.988, 
2.151, 2.278)), .Names = c("Days to maturity", "Yield to maturity"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

So far I got the following:

```
library(readxl)
Synthetic_bond_creation <- read_excel("~/UZH/Bachelorarbeit/Synthetic bond 
creation.xlsx")
View(Synthetic_bond_creation)
plot(Synthetic_bond_creation$`Days to maturity`, 
Synthetic_bond_creation$`Yield to maturity`, xlab = "Days to maturity", ylab 
= "Yield to maturity in %", main = "Bonds of 'Societe Generale SA' on 
13.03.2013")
abline(lm (Synthetic_bond_creation$`Yield to maturity` ~ 
Synthetic_bond_creation$`Days to maturity`))
```

[image: rplotsynthetic]

Now I would like to construct a synthetic 5-year bond, which means I need to have the values on the regression line at x=1300 for the Day to maturity and the respective y-value.

I tried to "draw" my goal in word which looks as follows:

[image: syntheticbond]

The dashed lines should be black.

Comment: Please, use `dput(Synthetic_bond_creation)` instead of `print(Synthetic_bond_creation)`

Comment: Ok, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example (using predicted values of the linear regression and some thresholds that you can adapt to your case).

```
# data and model
df <- mtcars
model <- lm(disp ~ mpg, data = df)
summary(model)
# plot model
plot(df$mpg, df$disp, xlab = "mpg", ylab = "disp")
pred.val <- predict(model)
lines(df$mpg, pred.val, lty = 1, col = "black")
# set thresholds
xmin <- 0
ymin <-  0
xmax <-  25 # suppose x = 25
ymax <-  as.numeric(predict(model, data.frame(mpg = xmax ))) # use x to get f(x)
# add segments
segments(x0 = xmax, y0 = ymin, x1 = xmax, y1 = ymax,
         lty = 2, col = "black") # vertical segment
segments(x0 = xmin, y0 = ymax, x1 = xmax, y1 = ymax,
         lty = 2, col = "black") # horizontal segment
```

[image]

```
# using ggplot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp))+
        geom_point() +
        geom_line(aes(y = fitted(model))) + 
        geom_segment(aes(x = xmax, # vertical segment
                         xend = xmax,
                         yend = ymax),
                     y = 0,
                     linetype = "dashed") + 
        geom_segment(aes(y = ymax, # horizontal segment
                         xend = xmax,
                         yend = ymax),
                     x = 0,
                     linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]